# Get a NoSuchMethodError:Spring Framework when I am not using Spring

Tags: java, maven, testng

I am running a normal automation case but I get this error :

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.isCglibProxyClass(Ljava/lang/Class;)Z
at org.apache.cxf.common.util.SpringAopClassHelper.getRealClassInternal(SpringAopClassHelper.java:86)
at org.apache.cxf.common.util.ClassHelper.getRealClass(ClassHelper.java:55)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.ProviderFactory.setCommonProviders(ProviderFactory.java:513)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.ClientProviderFactory.setProviders(ClientProviderFactory.java:91)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.ProviderFactory.initBaseFactory(ProviderFactory.java:138)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.ClientProviderFactory.initBaseFactory(ClientProviderFactory.java:81)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.ClientProviderFactory.createInstance(ClientProviderFactory.java:56)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.JAXRSClientFactoryBean.initClient(JAXRSClientFactoryBean.java:364)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.JAXRSClientFactoryBean.createWebClient(JAXRSClientFactoryBean.java:212)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.spec.ClientImpl$WebTargetImpl.initTargetClientIfNeeded(ClientImpl.java:270)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.spec.ClientImpl$WebTargetImpl.request(ClientImpl.java:232)
```

The puzzling thing is I am not using anything related to Spring.

And my pom file which has Spring Version 3.0.3
[image]

If I run the code in a *new* workspace it will run the first time - but after that it will start throwing the above error. Also, if I build the project before running this code it won't work.

Comment: Show us your pom.xml please.

Comment: "I am not using anything related to Spring." - what do you mean? you have it in pom.xml

Comment: @ACV I was not calling any Spring functionality in my code. Ofcourse I've it in my pom.xml

Comment: In Spring Boot for example if you include some dependencies im pom.xml they get picked automatically. For example, if you add JPA support, it will ask you to configure the DB connection. The same may happen in this situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked with a few folks and I got to know that a few dependencies in pom file were conflicting with each other. One of the added dependencies was invoking a different REST client in conflict with another REST client which had already been invoked by a dependency placed earlier in the pom file.

Re-ordering the dependencies in the pom file helped remove the error.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like Apache CXF sees Spring as available and tries to use it in ClassHelper, see also https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-6191 and https://github.com/apache/cxf/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/apache/cxf/common/util/ClassHelper.java#L40.

And Spring most probably comes as a dependency for some component, it's pretty common these days :) You can pin point who needs it by running `mvn dependency:tree` from the command line or using dependency tree view in your IDE.